# Adding bigimg to beautiful-jekyll

Tags: jekyll, r-markdown

My website on github uses the beautiful-jekyll template. And have been up and running for a while now.  Added the "bigimg:" parameter on YAML front matter parameters with the respective path to the images to be displayed, but the image do  not render as intended. What might be causing this?

The index.html Yaml contains this

```
bigimg:
- "/img/big-imgs/image_one.jpg" : "Image One"
```

The image is uploaded.

Comment: Let's take a look at your repo first.

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful-jekyll version is old, and doesn't support the `bigimg` parameter.